# Update all fkeys to point to a new pkey

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have a table of IDs, which are a non-nullable serialized primary key set, and I have... let's say 500 tables with columns with fkey constraints binding them to the IDs.

I realize that someone entered an incorrect entry (Let's say entry #10001) in the primary ID table.  They also entered 500 rows into 500 tables, all pointing to #10001.  They need to point to #10000, as #10000 already existed.  So I need to go through to every fkey that references that ID, and change #10001 to #10000, so that I can delete #10001 without deleting records meant for #10000.

Is there a fast and safe way to do this?  I know that I can't delete the ID until all fkeys pointing to it are deleted, or they would become referentially orphaned (and I think PGSQL rejects it due to constraint violation anyway).

I can't manually do it every time, as mistakes occur... often enough, and there's hundreds of tables to go through.

I'm trying to see if I can iterate over all the fkey constraints in the information_schema.table_constraints table, but there's... poor naming for the fkeys.  I'm hoping I don't need to manually construct consistently named fkeys, because that involves going through and renaming all the fkey constraints.  I can if needed, though - is there a way to programmatically iterate over all existing fkey constraints, and check what they link, to see if it's a link that needs to be taken into account for updating?

Thank you for any advice you can provide!

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your question, someone entered data that points to `10000` as the foreign key identifier, however, they data that was entered should be pointing towards `10001`?

Comment: You can get the [SQL behind various `psql` commands](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/131031/5359), that might help you backtrack from, say, `\d some_table` (which includes all the information you want) to the necessary parts of `pg_catalog`.

Comment: @electricjelly yes.   

I'll try playing around and seeing what I can do.

Comment: do all the record entered incorrectly have some sort of timestamp associated? in order to accomplish what you want, you will need some sort of identifier to use, and you may have to be creative.

Comment: @electricjelly Everything that was entered incorrectly has the erroneous ID on it, so it's trivial to figure out what needs to be changed.